# I'm trying to include an image into a GitLab Jekyll website hosted on an external server, but it's not working

Tags: gitlab, jekyll

I have a jekyll website, with my repository in GitLab while the website itself is hosted on an external server. So far everything works (the website is up and both posts and layouts do what I want them to) but I have trouble assessing images or other files (pdf, css).

My repository is structured like this:

_assets
   example.jpg
_layout
   example_layout
the website is hosted at SERVERURL/~myURL/, with my baseurl being /~myURL

I'm trying to access the jpg from the example_layout but it doesn't work. I've tried finding an answer, including reading similiar questions, and it seems the problem is because the website is being hosted externally. What I've found as suggestions so far that didn't work:

href="{{ site.baseurl }}/_assets/example.jpg" 
href="../_assets/example.jpg"
href="_assets/example.jpg"
href="/_assets/example.jpg"
I'm new to both jekyll and GitLab, so I'm currently out of ideas and would be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If you host your image in **_assets**, they are not processed, and copied by jekyll in **_site** folder.

You need to add **_assets** to your `include` parameter in **_config.yml**.

```
include:
  - _assets
  - ...
```